# Different ways of proveing sets equal

Tags: set-theory

I've been learning about sets and I'm trying to find different methods for proving two of them equal.

Example: Suppose I want to prove following identity for sets $A$, $B$ and $C$:

$A \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$

---

Proof 1 : Exclusion and Inclusion (I tried to prove both at the same time, I hope it's still rigorous)
\begin{align}
&x \in A \cup (B \cap C) \\
\iff& x\in A  \,\,\lor\,\,  x\in(B\cap C) \\\iff& x\in A  \,\,\lor\,\,  (x\in B \,\, \land \,\, x\in C) \\\iff& (x\in A  \,\,\lor\,\,  x\in B) \,\, \land \,\, (x\in A  \,\,\lor\,\,x\in C) \\\iff& (x\in A  \cup B) \,\, \land \,\, (x\in A  \cup C) \\\iff& x \in (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)
\end{align}

---

Proof 2: Truthtable

| $x \in A$ | $x \in B$ | $x \in C$ | $x \in B \cap C$ | $x \in A \cup (B \cap C)$ | $x\in A \cup B$ | $x \in A \cup C$ | $x \in (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $t$ | $t$ | $t$ | $t$ | $t$ | $t$ | $t$ | $t$ |
| $t$ | $t$ | $f$ | $f$ | $t$ | $t$ | $t$ | $t$ |
| $t$ | $f$ | $t$ | $f$ | $t$ | $t$ | $t$ | $t$ |
| $t$ | $f$ | $f$ | $f$ | $t$ | $t$ | $t$ | $t$ |
| $f$ | $t$ | $t$ | $t$ | $t$ | $t$ | $t$ | $t$ |
| $f$ | $t$ | $f$ | $f$ | $f$ | $t$ | $f$ | $f$ |
| $f$ | $f$ | $t$ | $f$ | $f$ | $f$ | $t$ | $f$ |
| $f$ | $f$ | $f$ | $f$ | $f$ | $f$ | $f$ | $f$ |

---

Proof 3: Ven-diagrams (not really rigorous)

---

Question: Are there other ways how I could proof this identity equal?

Comment: Your two methods of proof used are the Truth Table Method, and the subset method ( show the sets are subsets of each other).  Another technique is to apply a identity/theorem, in order to rewrite one side as the other side. Also, while not common for this type of problem, it is possible to use a proof by contradiction- assume that they aren't equal and derive a contradiction. If they aren't equal, consider two cases: Either the left hand side has an element that the right hand side doesn't, or vice versa.

Comment: Could you showcase your suggestions?